# print address of array of char

Tags: c++, char, cout, ostream

```c
int *i = new int(1);
cout << i << endl;
```

Will print the address of the integer.

```
    char *c="cstring";
    cout << c << endl;
    cout << &(*c) << endl;
```

Will both print "cstring". I guess this behavior can simply be explained with the implementation of `ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const char* s );` in the IOstream Library.

But what to do if you actually want to print the address of the data c refers to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(c) << endl;
```

or just

```
cout << (void*)c << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting it as a `const void*` :

```
cout << static_cast<const void*>(c) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just

```
cout << &c << endl;
```

Works for me :)

Comment: no it doesn't. this will give you the adress of the pointer. not the adress of what this pointer points to.