# Why does a char seem to take more space in an array than by itself

Tags: c++, pointers, char, memory-address

```
char testChar = 'a';
char myCharString[] = "asd";
char *pointerToFirstChar = &(myCharString[0]);
char *pointerToSecondChar = &(myCharString[1]);
cout << "A char takes " << sizeof(testChar) << " byte(s)";
cout << "Value was " << pointerToFirstChar << ", address: " << &pointerToFirstChar << endl;
cout << "Value 2 was " << pointerToSecondChar << ", address:" << &pointerToSecondChar << endl;
```

this outputs:

> "A char takes 1 byte"
>
> "... address: 00F3F718"
>
> "... address: 00F3F70C",

I'm thinking the difference between addresses should be 1 byte, since that would be the size of the data separating them. Why is it not so?

Comment: You're taking the address of the pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&pointerToFirstChar` and `&pointerToSecondChar`, you're not taking the address of the elements of the `char` array, but the address of the local variable `pointerToFirstChar` and `pointerToSecondChar`. Note they've been pointers themselves.

You might want:

```
cout << "Value was " << pointerToFirstChar << ", address: " << static_cast<void*>(pointerToFirstChar) << endl;
cout << "Value 2 was " << pointerToSecondChar << ", address:" << static_cast<void*>(pointerToSecondChar) << endl;
```

Note you need to cast them to `void*` to print out the address instead of the string.

Comment: @downvoter: Please tell me where am I wrong so I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the addresses of the *pointers* `pointerToFirstChar` and `pointerToSecondChar`. They are pointers to char; compare their *values* and  those will differ by 1.  You seem to have edited that out in your text.

Answer (score 0):

you are printing address of pointer variable and not the address currently pointer is holding.

for example:

> ```
> &myCharString[0] = 0xFE20  
> &myCharString[1] = 0xFE21  
> &myCharString[2] = 0xFE23
> ```

```
char *pointerToFirstChar = &(myCharString[0]);
```

Address of pointerToFirstChar = 0xF8C2 and it holds the address &myCharString[0] = 0xFE20

so you are printing, 0xF8C2 rather than printing 0xFE20

Update your code as follows to get the correct result.

`cout << "Value was " << pointerToFirstChar << ", address: " << (void *)&pointerToFirstChar[0] << endl;
cout << "Value 2 was " << pointerToSecondChar << ", address:" << (void *)&pointerToSecondChar[0] << endl;`

For more information please follow the below link
[print address of array of char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537621/print-address-of-array-of-char)